# Ayuda... ¿Cómo actualizar el campo de una tabla dependiendo del tipo de boton que selecciones?

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp

votar en contra
favorito
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo que pasa es que quiero actualizar el campo del Estado donde dice "Pendiente" usando un boton que me lo cambié a "Aceptado" o "Rechazado" y depués que se actualice en la base de datos... Hasta ahora use una función con JavaScript para hacer que cambie de "Pendiente" a "Aceptado" o "Rechazado" pero solo me permite hacerlo una vez.... Entonces ¿como puedo arreglar eso?

Y en la imagen que adjunto así es como se ve, pero sigo con eso de que solo me deja poner Aceptar una vez pero me gustaría saber como puedo ponerle una condición para decirle que si quiero hacer el cambio o que no quiero cambiar nada

Agradecería muchisimo su ayuda

```js
function x(){

var frase = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var frase4 = frase.replace(/Pendiente/gi,'Aceptar');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = frase4;

}

function x2(){

var frase = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
var frase4 = frase.replace(/Pendiente/gi,'Rechazar');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = frase4;

}
```

```html
    <table border="1">
    <tr>        
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Fecha de Solicitud</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Días Vacaciones</th>
    <th>Días Fin de semana</th>
    <th>Fecha Inicial</th>
    <th>Fecha Final</th>
    <th>Detalles</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    
    <th id="LB">Aceptar</th>
    <th id="LB">Rechazar</th>
    </tr>
    
   <%
       while(rs.next()){
       out.println("<tr>");
       out.println("<td name=idd>"+rs.getString("Id_Usuario")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FS")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("Nombre")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("DVacaciones")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("DFinde")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FInicio")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FFinal")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("Detalle")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td id=demo name=demo>"+rs.getString("Estado")+"</td>");
   
   %>
    
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Aceptar" onclick="x()">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Rechazar" onclick="x2()">    
    </td>
<script>

</script>
       </td>
       <%
       out.println("</tr>");
        }

        if(request.getParameter("rad")!=null){

         String est=request.getParameter("demo");
         String id2=request.getParameter("idd");

         stm.executeUpdate("Update Usuarios set Id_Usuario='"+id2+"', "
         
         + " Estado='"+est+"' "

         + " where Id_Usuario='"+id2+"' ");

         request.getRequestDispatcher("Solicitudes.jsp").forward(request, response);

         }

             rs.close();
             stm.close();
             conexion.close();
        %>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Creo que te estás complicando mucho.

Lo primero, voy a suponer que `id` es único. Veo que tienes dos `id=3` pero entiendo que esto no es correcto. El objetivo de un `id` es precisamente identificar unívocamente los valores (las peticiones, en este caso). Revísalo.

Dicho lo cual, si lo que quieres es simplemente cambiar el valor del `td` con `id="demo"` con Javacript puro lo mejor es que hagas algo como esto:

```
<%
       while(rs.next()){
       out.println("<tr>");
       out.println("<td name='id"+rs.getString("Id_Usuario")+"'>"+rs.getString("Id_Usuario")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FS")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("Nombre")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("DVacaciones")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("DFinde")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FInicio")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("FFinal")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td>"+rs.getString("Detalle")+"</td>");                      
       out.println("<td id='demo" + rs.getString("Id_Usuario") + "' name='demo" + rs.getString("Id_Usuario") + "'>"+rs.getString("Estado")+"</td>");
       out.println("<td><input type='button' name='rad' value='Aceptar' onclick='x('Aceptar',"+rs.getString("Id_Usuario")+"/><td>");
       out.println("<td><input type='button' name='rad' value='Aceptar' onclick='x('Rechazar',"+rs.getString("Id_Usuario")+"/><td>");      
       %>
```

Aprovechando que tienes el `rs` puedes meter también los botones en él y tener un único método `x(str,id)` al que le pasas el string a poner y el identificador del `td` a cambiar `demo+id`

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo de cómo funcionaría (sin la parte de JSP, simplemente con datos ya generados)

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>        
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Fecha de Solicitud</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Días Vacaciones</th>
    <th>Días Fin de semana</th>
    <th>Fecha Inicial</th>
    <th>Fecha Final</th>
    <th>Detalles</th>
    <th>Estado</th>
    
    <th id="LB">Aceptar</th>
    <th id="LB">Rechazar</th>
    </tr>
   <tr>
     <td id="id4">4</td>
    <td>23-06-2018</td>
    <td>Jack</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2018-03-13</td>
    <td>2018-03-26</td>
    <td>JAJA</td>
    <td id="demo4" name="demo4">Pendiente</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Aceptar" onclick="x('Aceptado', 4)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Rechazar" onclick="x('Rechazado', 4)">    
    </td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>
     <td id="id3">3</td>
    <td>23-06-2017</td>
    <td>Ben</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>2018-03-14</td>
    <td>2018-03-21</td>
    <td>JEJE</td>
    <td id="demo3" name="demo3">Aceptar</td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Aceptar" onclick="x('Aceptado', 3)">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" name="rad" value="Rechazar" onclick="x('Rechazado', 3)">    
    </td>
   </tr> 
   </table>
   
   <script>
   function x(str, id){
document.getElementById("demo"+id).innerHTML = str;

}
   </script>
```

Comment: Oye gracias por la ayuda en eso del cambio, lo estoy probando, crees, que si hago que se cambien así solamente y despues le agrego no sé un boton extra que que me actualice latabla dentro de la base de datos funcione?

Comment: No, tienes que hacer la actualización en el mismo botón. No tiene sentido hacerlo en otro. Te he entendido que esa parte ya la tienes...

Comment: Ya probé con el de jsp que me dejaste pero no me sale :'(

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta con el código y dinos cuál es el fallo. Mi solución es una orientación.

Comment: Ya puse como es que tengo el código  pero sigue sin cambiarme el parametro del estado

Comment: He editado mi respuesta porque había alguna cosa más. Ya te digo que la parte del bucle no la he probado. Tendría que quedarte algo con una estructura similar a la del ejemplo funcional que he puesto.

Comment: Edito mi respuesta y te muestro como lo tengo, a lo mejor es la función la que no esta funcionando

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75245/discussion-between-kiko-l-and-ben-escobar).